# how to select option in context menu c #

Tags: winforms

hello I'm grabbing a windows form application in c # and have a question about a context menu I have my main form within the main form I have a picturebox and I created an event as the next mouse click

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
         ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
         cm.MenuItems.Add("DISPONIBLE");
         cm.MenuItems.Add("RESERVAR");
         cm.MenuItems.Add("OCUPADA");
         pictureBox1.ContextMenu = cm;
    }
}
```

all going well so far shows me my contextual menu when I right click but when I choose the option to "AVAILABLE" another windows form show me someone who can help me please thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not the way. if you did so you need to call show for the context menu, you can set that menu at the initialization of the form or the control, you create the context menu one time it will be shown automatically, you don't have to create it each time you click the control, Add the following code to the constructor of the form just to check if it works

```
         ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
         cm.MenuItems.Add("DISPONIBLE");
         cm.MenuItems.Add("RESERVAR");
         cm.MenuItems.Add("OCUPADA");
         pictureBox1.ContextMenu = cm;
```

Comment: thank you very much and we can resolve what it was raising bad
guide me this video and it suits my program                                  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgDKcdC7X3E